# Auto complete by end/middle of line in bash

Tags: bash

In bash is there a quick way to do tab auto-completion based on the middle of a word.

So for example, if I have these files in a directory:

```
001_apple.txt 002_pear.txt 003_dog.txt
```

I would like to type the sequence: `*d<TAB>` to auto-complete 003_dog.txt.

Can this be done in bash? Is it easier to do in other shells?

Answer (score 6):

Try ESC-g for glob expansion.

And you should always install the bash-completion package (included by default often, but you need to source it in your bash profile script).

Comment: cool trick, only issue is that it seems not allow you to cycle between multiple options

Comment: At least if you repeat it, it lists the options.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like [zsh does this](http://zsh.dotsrc.org/FAQ/zshfaq04.html) plus quite a bit more. See: expand-or-complete-prefix and COMPLETE_IN_WORD options.

[Fish](http://fishshell.org/) also does this really nicely out-of-the-box.

Comment: Both links seem to be dead.

Answer (score 2):

```
ls *d*<TAB>
```

works in bash. Not sure if that's what Ben meant. `ls` could of course be any other command.

Comment: Odd somehow when I type it in my shell it does not allow me to expand, ls *d* does work as expected but tab is not expanding it ...

Comment: Nor in mine so, if answerer has it working, it must be a config item.

Comment: Maybe it's the "shopt -s extglob progcomp" option. Try running that command and then reattempt.

Comment: OP wants autocomplete, not shell globbing.

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute 
`` `ls *d*` ``
 to achieve the same effect, not quite as convenient as tab-completion however

Comment: Or, rather than "`ls *d*`", you could just use the sequence "*d*" which has the same effect without invoking a subshell. Or, for the truly masochistic,  "$(ls $(ls $(ls *d*)))" :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a feature of readline (may even not the default keybinding):

type `ls \*middle\*`, then type `ctrl-x, *` will replace `\*middle\*` with the files that match the pattern.